# Having items side by side in a card with Material-UI

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I'm currently working on displaying user profile details. I am trying to have a card set with the information listed below. I would like those items to sit side by side instead of divded how they are in the image below.

I've tried giving each items a Grid Item but it simply put them all listed below . I am trying to get `skills` and `home phone` to sit side by side in the same row
with `can also work` and `cell phone` sit side by side as well

[image: Card]

```
                        <Grid container spacing={32} justify="center">
                            <Grid item>
                                <PersonImage
                                    personId={metadata.id}
                                    height={175}
                                    width={175}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                                <Grid
                                    container
                                    spacing={0}
                                    direction="column"
                                    justify="center"
                                    alignItems="stretch">
                                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                                        <Card>
                                            <InfoLabel
                                                label="Skills"
                                                text={profile.skills}
                                            />
                                            <InfoLabel
                                                label="Can Also Work"
                                                text={profile.work}
                                            />
                                            <Grid
                                                container
                                                spacing={16}
                                                justify="center">
                                                <Grid item>
                                                    <InfoLabel
                                                        label="Home Phone"
                                                        text={
                                                            contactInfo.homePhone
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                    <InfoLabel
                                                        label="Cell Phone"
                                                        text={
                                                            contactInfo.mobilePhone
                                                        }
                                                    />

                                                    <InfoLabel
                                                        label="Email"
                                                        text={contactInfo.email}
                                                    />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Grid for that purpose.

You have some problems with your grid layout and your spacing is way to high. The spacing should be below 12 and too much spacing will push the content into the next row, which is what is happening here.

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lhuvw) to show you, how you could set up your grid. It is missing most of the styling but the layout is like you want it.